# How to ensure rendering cache invalidates after a direct edit to the .CSHTML file

Tags: caching, html-caching

I have a case where I needed to apply a hotfix to a component CSHTML view file. I edited the file on both of our Content Delivery servers. I also cleared the entire Sitecore cache via `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`. At that point I was expecting to see the updated HTML on the front end, but it was still in its previous state.

It wasn't until I recycled the IIS app pools that the HTML was updated. If I recall correctly, on all of my other Sitecore projects, whenever a view file was edited and saved, the front end would update almost instantaneously. Why isn't this happening in this case?

Here are the cache settings on the component:

[image: Rendering Cache Settings]

Setup:

- Sitecore 9.0.2
- Content Management server
- Two Content Delivery servers

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to clean the HTML cache is to trigger publish.

Sitecore doesn't have watchers on .cshtml files, so it is expected behavior.

Comment: Fair -- though I have evidence that the view cache is in fact cleared on downstream environments but not the PROD environment when making view changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the `htmlCacheSize` property to your `<sites>` node for the website and set cacheHtml property of sites to true to enable the HTML output cache for that site.

Typically these properties come for the website of the `<sites>` but if you have multisite set up in which your site node is patched then you need to adjust these settings accordingly.

As Sitecore clears HTML cache at each publishing, make sure all of your websites are added to `Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer` handler to clear the HTML cache of the sites at `publish:end` event.